# Ionic SignalR Warning: No client method with the name 'X' found

Tags: asp.net, angular, signalr, ionic4, abp

I have an ABP.IO v4.4.2 project (.NET Core / Angular / Ionic)
I'm using SignalR on angular and ionic(Android App)

when i send signalR to all clients in Web app (Angular or Ionic)
it gives me warning and proceeds with code

> `Warning: No client method with the name 'XX' found.`

but when i send signalR to all clients in Android app it gives me the same warning and stops

And this only happens when i send SignalR to all Clients

**C# code**

```cs
 public async Task HandleEventAsync(DriverClientBookingUpdateEto bookingUpdateEto)
        {

            if (bookingUpdateEto.BookingTimeFrame == BookingTimeFrame.Future)
            {
                await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("DriverClientBookingUpdate", bookingUpdateEto);
            }

            else
            {
                string _groupName = bookingUpdateEto.Id.ToString();

                if (bookingUpdateEto.ConnectionIds.Count == 0)
                {
                    await _hubContext.Clients.Group(_groupName).SendAsync("DriverClientBookingUpdate", bookingUpdateEto);
                }

                else if (bookingUpdateEto.ConnectionIds.Count == 1)
                {
                    await _hubContext.Clients.Client(bookingUpdateEto.ConnectionIds[0]).SendAsync("DriverClientBookingUpdate", bookingUpdateEto);
                }

                else if (bookingUpdateEto.ConnectionIds.Count > 1)
                {
                    AddSurroundingDriversConnectionIdToGroup(bookingUpdateEto.ConnectionIds, _groupName);
                    await _hubContext.Clients.Group(_groupName).SendAsync("DriverClientBookingUpdate", bookingUpdateEto);
                }
            }
        }
```

**Typescript code**

```js
    private registerSignalEvents() {
    
        this.hubConnection.on('DriverClientBookingUpdate', (order: OrderModel) => {
          this.orderSvc.handleOrderUpdate(order);
        });
      }
```

Comment: How does it "stop"? Is there an exception with a stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added `console.log()` in handleOrderUpdate() method to try and debug it.
And now it works. I have no idea why; it's so unpredictable